# Laravel - User table, make id uuid type

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, factory, uuid, laravel-5.8

***1- User table, make id uuid type.***

*No problem*

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

*But this error*

```
php artisan db:seed
```

*Error : ("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'id' doesn't have a default value")*

***2- Also companies want to be randomly distributed to users. In the user table, uuid type will be held in the user_id column.***

***Thank you from now...***

*User Model :*

```
use UsesUuid;

protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password', 'role', 'slug',];

protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token',];

protected $casts = ['email_verified_at' => 'datetime',];

public function companies()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Company', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

*UsesUuid trait:*

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::creating(function ($post) {
        $post->{$post->getKeyName()} = (string)Str::uuid();
    });
}

public $incrementing = false;

public function getKeyType()
{
    return 'string';
}
```

*Users migration:*

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->uuid('id')->primary()->unique();
        $table->string('name',100);
        $table->string('email',100);
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password',100);
        $table->string('role',20)->nullable();
        $table->string('slug',100);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
```

*Companies migration:*

```
Schema::create('companies', function (Blueprint $table) {
$table->bigIncrements('id');
$table->string('user_id',36);
$table->string('name', 100);

$table->timestamps();
$table->softDeletes();

$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
```

});

*User factory:*

```
$name = $faker->name;
return [
    'id' => Str::uuid(),
    'name' => $name,
    'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
    'email_verified_at' => now(),
    'password' => Hash::make(123), // password
    'remember_token' => Str::random(10),
    'role' => 'user',
    'slug' => Str::slug($name),
];
```

Company factory:

```
$name = $faker->company;
return [
    'user_id' => Str::uuid(),
    'name' => $name,
];
```

*DatabaseSeeder :*

```
factory(App\User::class, 5)->create();
factory(App\Company::class, 1500)->create();
```

Comment: `General error: 1364 Field 'id' doesn't have a default value")`, make `id` column as auto increment or provide a value from code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

modify your trait like this:

```
static::creating(function ($post) {
    empty($post->{$post->getKeyName()}) && $post->{$post->getKeyName()} = (string)Str::uuid();
});
```

there is no need to make UUID unique, 
in your migration, because it is already!

```
$table->uuid('id');
$table->primary('id');
```

and factory must create primary UUID itself, don't add it yourself

I think with these changes, seeder must run successfully

Comment: What should I do? Error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `bulursun.com`.`companies` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorr
ectly formed") (SQL: alter table `companies` add constraint `companies_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`) on delete cascade)

Comment: in company factory instead of creating new UUID, just select one  user id randomly, because we have a constraint on this field

Comment: 'user_id' => User::where('deleted_at', null)->inRandomOrder()->first()->id;

Comment: also it would be better to use : $table->uuid('user_id); in your migration instead of string with 36 character